# Hewitt–Savage zero–one law

Tags: probability-theory

All hail the teacher did not read the solution to the problem and asked for proof of the Hewitt-Savage law. I’ve been trying to Google the evidence, but I haven’t found anything. Does anyone have any reference to proof of law or reference to evidence textbooks.
Thank you and sorry if my English wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof can be found in the original paper.

*Hewitt, Edwin; Savage, Leonard J.*, [**Symmetric measures on Cartesian products**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1992999), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 80, 470-501 (1955). [ZBL0066.29604](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0066.29604).